# How to append items in Swift dictionary?

Tags: swift, dictionary

I'm new to Swift. I'd like to know how to append an item to this dictionary.

```
var areas_default: [String: [String: Any]] = ["": ["": Any]]
var default_area: Bool = false

for area in areas {
    default_area = area.value["default"] as! Bool
    if (default_area == true) {
        areas_default["areas"].append
    }
}
```

Comment: It's a little confusing what you want... `[String:[String:Any]]` is a dictionary, not an array (and also doesn't contain an array, unless `Any` is an array). Also, you can't initialize this data structure like this, `Any` is a type and can't be instantiated.

Comment: Maybe you could add a sample of what the dictionary content looks like once you have added a value

Answer (score 2):

Try the following approach:

```
var areas: [String: [String: Bool]] = ["ATrue": ["A": true]]

for (_, _) in areas {
    areas["BFalse"] = ["B": false]
}
```

Let's print it:

```
print(areas)

// ["BFalse": ["B": false], "ATrue": ["A": true]]
```

Or you can use `updateValue` instance method:

```
areas.updateValue(["B": false], forKey: "BFalse")
```